# Order of operations of pointer character

Tags: c, pointers

When doing an iteration, if I have the following:

```
while(*pstring)
    printf("%c", *pstring++);
```

It seems to do things in this order:

```
while(*pstring) {
    printf("%c", *pstring);
    pstring++;
}
```

Or, in other words, like this:

```
while(*pstring)
    printf("%c", *(pstring++));
```

Why doesn't it act like the following way instead:

```
while(*pstring)
    printf("%c", (*pstring)++);
```

Comment: `printf("%c", (*pstring)++);` adds `1` to the value at that address leaving the pointer unchanged. See [C-operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the expression `*pstring++` your are using what's called the ***post-increment*** operator (++ *after* a variable name). What this does is 'evaluate' the expression **first** and then increments it. So, in this case, the `*` operator is applied to the value pointed to by `pstring` ***before*** it is incremented.

If, on the other hand, you used `*++pstring`, then you are using the ***pre-increment*** operator: the value of `pstring` would be incremented **before** its address is used by the `*` operator.

Try it, and see (but be careful, you may run into undefined behaviour when you go beyond the end of your character string)!

Comment: How does the `++` increment know to work on `pstring` then instead of `*pstring` ?

Comment: In this case, the post-increment `++` operator has a higher precedence than the indirection `*` operator, so it is evaluated first (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). In the case of `*++pstring` it's a bit trickier, as the pre-increment `++` operator has the **same** precedence as `*`, so we have to look at things in a 'right-to-left` order.